# Reflection Injection vulnerability

Tags: html, controller

while running a seeker scan, I encountered a  Reflection Injection vulnerability.

The razor HTML has a Telerik Grid call which is calling a controller function. I am passing a variable 'filter' can be one of 20 columns I have in the Grid.

The vulnerability is 'endpoint can be modified to execute one of the following field/method names' and lists all the column names

How do I take care of this? Please share your inputs

Comment: Can somebody please help

Comment: Hi shemmige, are you a developer of the project? If yes, can you please open a Support Ticket here https://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets?supcId=cjj5ut7e400003a6jaog0hzgq.  If you're not a dev on that project, can you please report it here instead => https://www.progress.com/security/vulnerability-reporting-policy. I will be able to escalate to the correct team and get some answers for you.